# Custom Fonts for non-English Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uifont

I installed a custom font however, my app runs on two languages. I noticed that the custom fonts work with English but not with non-English. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose a custom font that includes "glyphs" for all of the special characters and punctuation that are needed for the language you are using. If the custom font you have is missing these extra glyphs, then you can either edit the font in a font editor such as Fontographer to add the missing glyphs (this requires drawing them in or copying parts from other letters), or finding a new version of the same font that includes the glyphs you need.

You can see the missing glyphs by opening a font that has these glyphs in the "Font Book" program included with mac os x. Then you can open your custom font and compare the two to see what's missing.

Also keep in mind that you usually need a custom license from the font owner to include fonts in your application.